# apply required attribute to checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox, required

can we apply required attribute to checkbox in html multiple checkbox?without use of javascript or jquery

I want to apply validation to html page without javascript.and warning message also be shown.answer don't contain any type of function etc.

Comment: if by _multiple checkbox_ you meant ***same named group of checkbox*** then the answer is no since _In the case of a same named group of checkbox input types, only the checkboxes with the required attribute are required._ and to enforce a required constraint to at least one of them to be checked would require js [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

Comment: yes I know that way .thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can be done with:

```
<!-- other code here -->
<input type="checkbox" required>
<!-- other code here -->
```

This will automatically give an error popup message if the checkbox is not filled in.

Comment: but it's work only in case of one checkbox element. i want multiple checkbox.

Comment: @kuno and you are pretty wrong indeed

Comment: why is that @DiegoD?

Comment: @kuno my first comment to the question contains the details with a reference to the mdn docs and the highlights that I cited as is. I'm afraid you didn't understand the question

Comment: @DiegoD yeah I might've misunderstood the question. if he wants it with multiple checkboxes but doesn't want a separate js file, he could always just use embedded js

Comment: @kuno the misunderstanding is escalating further

Comment: I'll just see myself out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply the required attribute to a checkbox in HTML, even when you have multiple checkboxes.

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="option1" required> Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="option2" required> Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="option3" required> Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="option4" required> Option 4</label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: but in that case i have to check all the checkbox right?

Comment: yes. you have check all where u don't want as required, please remove required attribute